# Automating application execution in windows task scheduler

Tags: vb.net, arguments, task, scheduler, execution

I am working on application which will have to be executed from windows task scheduler once a day. It is written in VB.net and right now it runs when RUN button is clicked. But how can I tell the windows task scheduler which subroutine to run when the application starts? Do I have to place the code to be executed into form load? Or can I pass an argument or something similar when calling the application in task scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Anything to be run by the task scheduler should not interact with the user and should be written as a console application and not a Windows Form application.

Console Application

```
Sub Main ()
    Dim taskToSchedule as New TaskToSchedule
    taskToSchedule.DoStuff()
End Sub
```

If you also need it to be run by a user then move the task functionality into a class library and invoke that from the button and the console app Sub Main.

Windows Form

```
Sub ButtonClick ()
    Dim taskToSchedule as New TaskToSchedule
    taskToSchedule.DoStuff()
End Sub
```